# A word meaning "going south to get north"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

I want to describe a situation when to get a south bound route you need to drive north. I'm looking for a noun. A couple possible suggestions I've seen:

"It is quite a bit of a diversion"

and

"It is quite a bit of a detour"

One could call it an "indirect route", but I'm looking for a noun, not an adjective.

Comment: The British expression is "around the houses"

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you've got to go "the long way round". I've used that before, but never thought about it before.

Answer (score 2):

*[Meander](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meander)* is a noun that refers to a bend in a sinuous or winding river.  Wikipedia notes,

> ...in Classical Greece the name of the river had become a common noun meaning anything convoluted and winding, such as decorative patterns or speech and ideas [...] Strabo said: "... its course is so exceedingly winding that everything winding is called meandering."

Thus, one might refer to a route as a *meander*, although  the adjectival form *meandering* is more frequently heard.
Some [related](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/acliq?r=12011405_1326516564_607533244) adjectives include *circuitous, roundabout, tortuous, winding, serpentine, crooked, sinuous, snaky*.   Some of these are also used as nouns; for example, *[serpentine](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/serpentine)* meanings include "coiled distillation tube".  One might plausibly call a winding route a *serpent*.

One could also say, "It's rather an [excursion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/excursion)" to indicate that a route is unnecessarily roundabout.

Comment: I think the problem with *meander* is if you describe the way someone spoke, say, as *meandering*, it tends to imply that they didn't actually end up making any substantive point at all. At least with *circuitous, roundabout, tortuous* we would normally suppose that they did have a point, which was in fact made - albeit not succinctly. So although it may work for a *route* (which by implication must actually end up getting to its destination), it doesn't transfer so well to other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

A common turn of phrase is:

> ["going around your elbow to get to your thumb"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22going+around+your+elbow+to+get+to+your+thumb%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

meaning a difficult method to get to something that should have been straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

[*Circumnavigation*](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=circumnavigation) is a noun for, literally, heading south to go north (or vice-versa, as your first sentence contradicts your headline; or perhaps your question is going south to get north?).

Answer (score 1):

A route that doubles back on itself can be called a *dogleg*.  E.g. if I want to travel by train from A to B, sometimes the fastest route is take a non-stop service that goes past B and stops at C, and then take a slow train from B to C.  This is called a *dogleg route*.

```
A -------------------------> C
                      B <---
```

Answer (score 0):

The term I would use is **reverse psychology**. As in "don't throw me into the briar patch."